# Java program find Length and number of vowels in String array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to get a String from the user and output it to a table including its number of words and its number of vowels, but I don't know how to count the vowels.

I tried the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array2 {

   public static void main(String[] args)
   { 
   
   
      Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);   
   
      int vowels = 0, length = 0;
   
      String[] values = new String[5]; 
      for (int i = 0; i<values.length; i++)
      {
         System.out.print("Enter the string:");
         values[i] = keyboard.nextLine();
         if(values[i].charAt(i) == 'a' ||values[i].charAt(i) == 'e' || values[i].charAt(i) == 'i' || values[i].charAt(i) == 'o' || values[i].charAt(i) == 'u')
         {
            vowels++;
         }
      
      }
      
   
      System.out.printf("%12s %15s %15s %15s\n","Number","Value", "Length", "Number of Vowels"); 
      int[] number = new int[5]; 
      for(int n=0; n<number.length;n++)
      {  
      
         System.out.printf("%10s %14s %18s %15s\n", n+1,values[n],vowels,values[n].length() ); 
         System.out.println();  
      }  
   
   } 
}
```

Comment: Instead of repeating all of those charAt == you could create a Set of the vowel characters or even just a String and check if the character is in the Set or string, or in any case you should factor out the values[i].charAt(i) into a variable so you aren't repeating that over and over again

Comment: You also need to wrap your Scanner in a try block as it's an AutoCloseable that will leak memory otherwise

Comment: @Novaterata, the OP didn't open System.in , so he should _not_ close the Scanner.

Comment: Do you really want to read five lines?

Comment: I already answered, but you ask this question a third time now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74100515/number-of-vowels-from-string-array

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues in your code.

1. You are limiting the number of inputs to `5` (When you define your `values` array).
2. You always check for `charAt(i)`, which will check only one character per input. Notice the `i` will be the same per input.

I'd try this approach. (Haven't tried this, so there might be compilation issues, but you'll get the point).

```java
public class Array2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);   
   
    int vowels = 0, length = 0;
   
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    while(true) {
      System.out.print("Enter the string (or EXIT to exit): ");
      String line = keyboard.nextLine();
      if (line.equals("EXIT")) {
        break; 
      }
      
      String[] words = line.split("\s+"); // Split the line by one or more white spaces. This will give the word count
      int wordCount = words.length();
      int vowelCount = countVowels(line);

      // Now you can add this to a table or anywhere
    } 
  }

  // I'd define a separate method to count vowels.
  private static int countVowels(string line) {
    Set<Character> vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
      if (vowels.contains(line.charAt(i)) {
        result++;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    vowels += values[i].length() - values[i].replaceAll("[AEIOUaeiou]", "").length();
}
```

I compare the length of the string with the length of the string without vowels